# Is there a way to seclude a loop in c++?

Tags: c++, windows

I'm trying to make an auto clicker with left and right mouse buttons but each with different delay, I'm quite familiar with lua so I'll try explain something similar in lua.

So in lua you could use a corontine and your function would look something like this...

```
coroutine.wrap(function()
    while (true) do
        --some code here
    end
end)
```

But this means is that we could stack them and run 2 loops simultaneously, I want to know if there's a way to do something similar in c++ so I could run 2 loops with different delays

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";

    while (true) {
        
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON)) {
            Sleep(65); // IF BOTH BUTTONS ARE DOWN THEN DELAY WOULD BE HIGHER
            INPUT iNPUT = { 0 };
            iNPUT.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
            iNPUT.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;
            SendInput(1, &iNPUT, sizeof(iNPUT));
            ZeroMemory(&iNPUT, sizeof(iNPUT));
            iNPUT.type = INPUT_MOUSE;;
            iNPUT.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;
            SendInput(1, &iNPUT, sizeof(iNPUT));
        }
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RBUTTON)) {
            Sleep(200); // IF BOTH BUTTONS ARE DOWN THEN DELAY WOULD BE HIGHER
            INPUT iNPUT = { 0 };
            iNPUT.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
            iNPUT.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN;
            SendInput(1, &iNPUT, sizeof(iNPUT));
            ZeroMemory(&iNPUT, sizeof(iNPUT));
            iNPUT.type = INPUT_MOUSE;;
            iNPUT.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP;
            SendInput(1, &iNPUT, sizeof(iNPUT));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: C++20 recently introduced [coroutines](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/coroutines) to the language. I'm not familiar enough with them yet to form an answer to your question, but you can read about it in the provided link.

Comment: There is also [Boost.coroutine](https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.coroutine).

Comment: If you want to stick to WinAPI, you can also consider [Fibers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/fibers).

Comment: Otherwise, use threads.

Comment: If both buttons are up, you’re doing a busy wait. Is that ok?

Comment: Check out **[GetKeyboardState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getkeyboardstate?redirectedfrom=MSDN)**, it returns the state of all [virtual keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes) in one call. Then you'd need a simple state machine to keep track of the delays.

Comment: @numzero Just changed that thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are *many* ways to do that. They fall in 3 categories.

1. **Threads.** They are like Lua coroutines but run in parallel instead of scheduled. That simplifies some things but requires extreme care in others. Since C++11 you can use its [native threads](http://cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/), that’s easier than using Windows API directly.
2. **Coroutines.** As pointed in the comments C++ has those since C++20, but Windows had them since ever: [fibers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/fibers). They work much like Lua coroutines but need a bit more setup.
3. **Action queue.** Use a queue ordered on absolute time (not delay) the action should be executed. Instead of calling `Sleep` and doing stuff afterwards, enqueue the action; at beginning of an iteration, check which queued action should be executed first and sleep just the time remaining to it before executing it (or do some other work until it’s time to execute some queued action).